# Where should I call code prior to render in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Many applications need to do some setup code such as plugin configuration prior to render. That code is sometimes the same on server and client, sometimes not. For example, I may want to execute something like the following:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

dayjs.extend(utc);

Modal.setAppElement('#modal-root');

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // Custom client-only setup.
}
```

In my own custom frameworks, I would've just called this in my setup script prior to calling `React.hydrate`. Where should I put it in next.js?

In some cases, I could do this setup inside of a `useEffect` hook in my page or custom app component, but in the examples above, it must be done prior to render as it may actually affect rendering.

Right now, I feel I'm forced to create a custom `_app.tsx` and put it in module scope above the component definition, but it's unclear if this is right or somehow dangerous/wrong.

It'd be great to have a `setup` function I could export from pages or the custom _app. Does such a thing exist? Am I thinking about this correctly?